# How to get all comment tags from html string using AngleSharp?

Tags: c#, comments, anglesharp

How would one go about finding all comment tags from HTML string using AngleSharp. The comments could be single as well as multiple lines.

```
<!-- Single line comment. -->

<!-- Multi-
ple line comment.
Lots      '""' '  "  ` ~ |}{556             of      !@#$%^&*())        lines
in
this
comme-
nt! -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve comment tags by using the `Descendents` extension method from `AngleSharp.Extensions.ApiExtensions`. Comments are not elements so you can't query for them like you normally can but this extension method allows you to retrieve nodes of a particular type.

```
IEnumerable<IComment> comments = document.Descendents<IComment>();
```

Example:

```
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Parser.Html;
using AngleSharp.Dom; // For IComment
using AngleSharp.Extensions; // For Descendents

var parser = new HtmlParser();
var source = @"<!-- Single line comment. -->
               <!-- Multi-
               ple line comment.
               Lots      '""""' '  ""  ` ~ |}{556             of      !@#$%^&*())        lines
               in
               this
               comme -
                nt!-->";
var document = parser.Parse(source);

// Get all comment nodes
IEnumerable<IComment> comments = document.Descendents<IComment>();

// Get the text in the comment nodes
foreach (IComment comment in comments)
{
    var textValue = comment.TextContent;
    ...
}
```